# Writing to file with fwrite appears successful, but no file appears

Tags: php, file, io

All I am attempting to do is append to a file, and then read the file. In this case, I am appending 'hi', so my results look like 'hi', 'hihi', 'hihihi', etc. This **works**. What is so baffling is that if I then look at my temp dir, I see no file /tmp/bb.txt. How am I able to append to a file I cannot find in my file system? Am I under some sort of fake root or something?

$content is becoming a longer string each time, so it must be saving somewhere. When I step through, $x is true.

```
    public function testFileAction()
{

    $file = '/tmp/bb.txt';
    $x = file_exists($file);
    $mf = fopen($file, 'a');
    fwrite($mf, 'hi');
    fclose($mf);
    $mfr = fopen($file, 'r');
    $content = fread($mfr, filesize($file));
    fclose($mfr);
    echo $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that '/tmp' might not mean the actual path of '/tmp' to php. Linux can be configured in a way that each process has its own tmp directory that it uses separately from any other process.

https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2012-11-05-fedora-private-tmp/

Answer (score 0):

Code is correct.

How are you running this? File can be owned by user used by server (apache for example).
You (user in the terminal) probably don't have permission to read the file.
Try `sudo ls /tmp`.

Comment: Even as superuser, I see no file in there. - I am running this code through a local apache server.

Comment: I've tested it on Ubuntu WSL. When PHP creates file and I had no read permission file appeared to be there, but empty, after chmodding it's contents were accessible. Fact that you don't see it might be from some account/system configuration? Try to make file yourself, and chmod it so everyone (apache) can read/write. Then run the script, and check the results. PHP doesn't appear to be the problem here.